# Retrieving column values pertaining to MIN(date) and MAX(date) in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My table structure is as follows:

```
| TxnID | CardID | WhereName    | FirstName | LastName  | DateTimeOfxTxn        | .....|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |  1     | location1    |   test    | employee1 | 2017-06-28 00:01:00   |      |
|   2   |  1     | location2    |   test    | employee1 | 2017-06-28 00:02:00   |      |
|   3   |  2     | location1    |   test    | employee2 | 2017-06-28 00:03:00   |      |
|   4   |  1     | location3    |   test    | employee1 | 2017-06-28 00:03:30   |      |
|   5   |  1     | location1    |   test    | employee1 | 2017-06-28 00:04:00   |      |
|   6   |  2     | location2    |   test    | employee2 | 2017-06-28 00:05:00   |      |
```

Right now, I have the following SQL query:

```
WITH t1 AS (
 SELECT
    CardID,
    MIN(DateTimeOfTxn) AS mindate,
    MAX(DateTimeOfTxn) AS maxdate
  FROM ActivityDataView 
  where convert(datetime, floor(convert(float, DateTimeOfTxn))) = '06/28/2017'
  GROUP BY CardID
)

SELECT
  t2.CardID,
  t2.WhereName as Location,
  t2.FirstName + ' ' + t2.LastName as Name,
  t1.mindate,
  t1.maxdate
FROM ActivityDataView AS t2
JOIN t1
  ON (t2.CardID = t1.CardID AND t2.DateTimeOfTxn = t1.mindate)
  OR (t2.CardID = t1.CardID AND t2.DateTimeOfTxn = t1.maxdate)
order by CardID
```

That query will select the row pertaining to the Min(date) and then also select the row for the Max(date).

Which returns me:

```
| CardID | Location     | Name             | MinDate               | MaxDate
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1     | location1    | test employee1   | 2017-06-28 00:01:00   | 2017-06-28 00:04:00  |
|  1     | location1    | test employee1   | 2017-06-28 00:01:00   | 2017-06-28 00:04:00  |
|  2     | location1    | test employee2   | 2017-06-28 00:03:00   | 2017-06-28 00:05:00  | 
|  2     | location2    | test employee2   | 2017-06-28 00:03:00   | 2017-06-28 00:05:00  |
```

I would like to be able to get this:

```
| CardID | Name             | MinDate               | MinLocation | MaxDate              | MaxLocation |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1     | test employee1   | 2017-06-28 00:01:00   | location1   | 2017-06-28 00:04:00  | location 1  |
|  2     | test employee2   | 2017-06-28 00:03:00   | location1   | 2017-06-28 00:05:00  | location 2  |
```

I'm pretty novice when it comes to SQL queries so I'm not sure how to achieve what I'm looking for.  Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by assigning row numbers in ascending and descending order of txntime and aggregating.

```
SELECT CardID
,MAX(CASE WHEN RN_MIN=1 THEN WHERENAME END) AS MINLOCATION
,MAX(CASE WHEN RN_MIN=1 THEN DateTimeOfTxn END) AS MINDATE
,MAX(CASE WHEN RN_MAX=1 THEN WHERENAME END) AS MAXLOCATION
,MAX(CASE WHEN RN_MAX=1 THEN DateTimeOfTxn END) AS MAXDATE
FROM (SELECT
       A.*
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CardID ORDER BY DateTimeOfTxn) as RN_MIN
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CardID ORDER BY DateTimeOfTxn DESC) as RN_MAX
       FROM ActivityDataView A
       WHERE cast(DateTimeOfTxn as date) = '2017-06-28'
     ) T
WHERE 1 IN (RN_MIN,RN_MAX)
GROUP BY CardID
```

It is unclear from which row the `name` and `location` in the expected output come from.

Comment: I apologize.  The "Location" column shouldn't exist in the expected outcome--only the MinLocation and MaxLocation columns.  That was a mistype.  Name is just an appended column of FirstName and LastName, which is tied to the CardID.

Comment: so the name comes from the min row or the max row?

Comment: It can be either as the name will be the same.  But your query looks like it's exactly what I need and can take it from here.  Thank you!